# How do I show the max value from the first column in a gray box

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to show the Max value from the first column from a table that is getting its stuff from a database. I don't know how to display the value in a small gray box below the table when I click show Max button. I am also using PHP and JavaScript.

Here is what I have tried in the main PHP file under the HTML portion:

```html
<p></p>
<table>
    <div id="showMaxdiv" style="display: open">
    <form action="getMaxValue.php" method="post">
        <input id="mn" type="hidden" name="mn" value="<?php print $mn ?>" />
    <tr>
        <td style="width:4em;background-color:lightgrey"><?php print $mn ?></td>
        <td style="width: 10em">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="showMaxVal()" value="Show Max"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the get Max value PHP file:

```php
<?php
$mn = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "mn"));

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "universitydb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$tblArr = array();
$tblArr[] = "student";
$tblArr[] = "course";
$tblArr[] = "section";
$tblArr[] = "grade_report";
$tblArr[] = "prerequisite";

$table_name = $tblArr[$mn];

$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $fields[] = $record['0'];
}

$query = "SELECT MAX($fields[0]) FROM  $table_name";

$out = "";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$line = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    $out = $col_value;
    break;
}

print $out;

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the JavaScript portion:

```js
function showMaxValJQ(u) {
    var myurl = "getMaxValue.php?mn=" + u;
    document.getElementById("showMaxdiv" + u).style.display = "open";
    $.get(myurl, function(data, status){
       $("#mymax").html(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: FYI: You can not put div or form into a table like that, this kind of nesting is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById("showMaxdiv" + u)` - what element are you trying to select here? There is only an element with the ID `showMaxdiv` in the code you have shown us; so unless `u` contained an empty string, what is this supposed to select?

Comment: `$("#mymax")` - can't see what this would select either. If there is more coding relevant to this than what you have shown us, then please edit your question with a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Create a button with an onclick event to call a JavaScript function that will retrieve the maximum value from the database using an AJAX request.

```
<p></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 4em;background-color: lightgrey"></td>
        <td style="width: 10em">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="showMaxVal()" value="Show Max"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="maxValue" style="background-color: lightgrey;"></div>

<script>
function showMaxVal() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("maxValue").innerHTML = "Max value: " + this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "getMaxValue.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Example getMaxValue.php:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "universitydb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT MAX(column_name) AS maximum FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxValue = $row['maximum'];

echo $maxValue;

mysqli_close($conn);
```